# tiny mce pop ups blank in smarty

Tags: smarty

I am using tiny mce with smarty but it shows blank pop ups such as in image,anchor,preview buttons. The code i have used in my tpl file is

> `{literal} 
>   
>   tinyMCE.init({ // General options mode
>   : "textareas", theme : "advanced",
>   plugins :
>   "safari,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template",
>
> // Theme options
>   theme_advanced_buttons1 :
>   "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
>   theme_advanced_toolbar_location :
>   "top", theme_advanced_toolbar_align :
>   "left",
>   theme_advanced_statusbar_location :
>   "bottom", theme_advanced_resizing :
>   true,
>
> // Example content CSS (should be your
>   site CSS) content_css :
>   "css/content.css",
>
> // Drop lists for
>   link/image/media/template dialogs
>   template_external_list_url :
>   "lists/template_list.js",
>   external_link_list_url :
>   "lists/link_list.js",
>   external_image_list_url :
>   "lists/image_list.js",
>   media_external_list_url :
>   "lists/media_list.js",
>
> // Replace values for the template
>   plugin template_replace_values : {
>   username : "Some User", staffid :
>   "991234" } });  {/literal}`

Comment: Please show the actual code rendered in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is solved by using
`document.domain = 'mydomain.com';`

above where one is intializing the tinymce script in tpl file.
and uncommenting the document.domain = 'mydomain.com'; in tiny_mce_popup.js file.